# Linux: brk() error 'Cannot allocate memory'

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, brk

I'm trying to use the brk() function in a C program. My goal is to use it directly (as part of a larger test) by checking the current program break (pb) with

```
void *current_break = sbrk(0);
```

executing a malloc (for testing as malloc should sometimes execute brk if the allocated space is large enough)

```
void* mallow_return = malloc(1);
```

and than directly executing brk() by using the current address + an increment (and check if this increase the pb):

```
int increase = 0x01; 
void * newbreak = current_break + increase;
int return_value = brk(&newbreak);
```

My problem is, that neither with a large malloc (malloc(5000;)) nor with (aligned or unaligned) brk() call the pb is changed. When checking the errno I get a

> Cannot allocate memory!`error (as given by`strerror(errno)

Can anybody see why I'm not able to increase the program break in anyway?

Thanks for any hints!

(System is: Debian 10 (buster) with kernel 4.19)

Edit: As requested this is the main function with includes:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{

printf("[+] Get current program break\n");
void *current_break = sbrk(0);
printf("\t[+] Current break point=\t%#x\n", current_break);


printf("[+] Malloc should call brk as well\n");
void* mallow_return = malloc(1);

printf("[+] Check if malloc changes PB\n");
void *after_break = sbrk(0);
printf("\t[+] After malloc pbreak=\t%#x\n", after_break);


int increase = 0x01; 
printf("\t[+] Increasing p-break direclyby %d\n", increase);


void * newbreak = current_break + increase;
printf("\t[+] Setting break point to=\t%#x\n", newbreak);


int return_value = brk(&newbreak);

//check if error was thrown
int errornumber = errno;
if (errornumber != 0)
{
    printf("\t[+] Error: %s!\n", strerror(errornumber)); 
    return -1;
}

//check if pb was set now
printf("\t[?] New program break value?\t%#x\n", sbrk(0));
printf("[?] Return value of brk: %d\n", return_value);

return;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some `#include`s and a small `main`? How do you check if "the program break is changed"? When and how do you check errno?

Comment: Remove the ampersand. Brk takes the break

Comment: Or use sbrk instead

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I added the main file above with all includes. Unfortunally i cannot use sbrk as I have to work with brk() (project-wise it is necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks to @Antii Haapala, who posted this as a comment.)

We need to remove the ampersand here:

> ```
> int return_value = brk(&newbreak);
> ```

That line should be simply

```
int return_value = brk(newbreak);
```

Comment: @TobySpeight This answer id the accepted answer posted by the asker of the original question as a self-answer. He is thanking the user who originally posted it as a comment.

Comment: @karel, I've edited so that this stands as an answer in its own right - thanks for the heads-up!